# How to work with CustomValidator and RequiredFieldValidator together in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side-validation

I have 3 text boxes current password,new password and confirm password and 3 RequiredFieldValidator for each text-box and one comparevalidator for new and confirm password.

I also use CustomValidator because i want to check whether the current password is correct.so i created one javascript function that check current password.

**Step:**

1.if current password is not correct it display alert message that "current password is not correct" which is OK.

2.but it move forward and also display alert message "New Password and Confirm Password Fields must be identical." if both are not matched.

What i want is it should not move further it display message in step 1.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

**PS:**

**ERROR**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the validator on your script like this:

```
 var CmpValidator = document.getElementById('<%=CompareValidator1.ClientID%>');
 ValidatorEnable(CmpValidator, false);
```

Later on client click of the submit button you can enable it like:

```
 var CmpValidator = document.getElementById('<%=CompareValidator1.ClientID%>');
 ValidatorEnable(CmpValidator, true);
```

Comment: I tried as per the solution given by you it giving me error.You can see error in my question.see the updated question

Answer (score 1):

Disable CompareValidator, disable client script for it and enable in the current password CustomValidator's server validation method depending on password validation result:

Markup:

```
Current password: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="CurrentPassword" TextMode="Password" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CurrentPasswordValidator" ValidateEmptyText="true"
ControlToValidate="CurrentPassword" OnServerValidate="CurrentPasswordValidator_ServerValidate"
ErrorMessage="current password is not correct" />
<br />
New Password: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="NewPassword1" TextMode="Password" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="NewPassword1" >*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<br />
Confirm Password: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="NewPassword2" TextMode="Password" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="NewPassword2" >*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="CompareNewPasswordsValidator"
     ControlToValidate="NewPassword2" ControlToCompare="NewPassword1" EnableClientScript="false"
     ErrorMessage="New Password and Confirm Password Fields must be identical" Enabled="false" />
<br /> 
<asp:Button ID="ResetPasswordButton" runat="server" Text="Reset Password" OnClick="ResetPasswordButton_Click" />
```

Code:

```
protected void CurrentPasswordValidator_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Value == "123")
    {
        args.IsValid = true;
        CompareNewPasswordsValidator.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
        CompareNewPasswordsValidator.Enabled = false;
    }
}

protected void ResetPasswordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid)
    {

    }
}
```